# updation query in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am facing the problem on update hql query on hibernate.

Here is my following class:

```
    --session configuration
     ExamResults examResults = new ExamResults();
     examResults.setTitle("cbse board jee");
     examResults.setId(2);
     String hql = "UPDATE EXAMRESULTS SET TITLE=:TITLE WHERE ID=:ID";
     Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
     query.setParameter("TITLE", examResults.getTitle());
     query.setParameter("ID", examResults.getId());
     int result = query.executeUpdate();
     System.out.println("Rows Effected=>"+result);


     session.save(examResults);

     tx.commit();

   }
}
```

On running the class, i am getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: EXAMRESULTS is not mapped [UPDATE EXAMRESULTS SET TITLE=:TITLE WHERE ID=:ID]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:181)
    ...
```

Also my bean class is here:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EXAMRESULTS")
public class ExamResults implements Serializable{

    private int id;
private String title;
private String body1;
private String body2;
private Date resultdate;
private String affiliation;
private int isactive;
private String url;
private String imageurl;
//private CommonsMultipartFile imageurlimg;
private String metatitle;
private String metadescription;
private String metakeywords;
private Date createddate;


    --getters & setters
```

What should be correct approach to resolve problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `EXAMRESULTS` try using `ExamResults` i.e. the class name of your entity. You need to use class name in your HQL queries instead of table name. So update the query to:

```
UPDATE ExamResults e SET e.TITLE=:TITLE WHERE e.ID=:ID
```

The HQL documentation mentions:

> With the exception of names of Java classes and properties, queries
>   are case-insensitive. So SeLeCT is the same as sELEct is the same as
>   SELECT, but org.hibernate.eg.FOO and org.hibernate.eg.Foo are
>   different, as are foo.barSet and foo.BARSET.

Documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e2551